# Different struct elements "written by continuous and procedural assignments"

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Why do I get :

```
# ** Error (suppressible): testbench.sv(27): (vopt-12003) Variable 'ar[0].subar[0]' written by continuous and procedural assignments. See testbench.sv(19). 
# ** Error (suppressible): testbench.sv(27): (vopt-12003) Variable 'ar[0].subar[1]' written by continuous and procedural assignments. See testbench.sv(19). 
# ** Error (suppressible): testbench.sv(27): (vopt-12003) Variable 'ar[0].subar[2]' written by continuous and procedural assignments. See testbench.sv(19). 
# ** Error (suppressible): testbench.sv(27): (vopt-12003) Variable 'ar[0].subar[3]' written by continuous and procedural assignments. See testbench.sv(19). 
# ** Error (suppressible): testbench.sv(27): (vopt-12003) Variable 'ar[1].subar[0]' written by continuous and procedural assignments. See testbench.sv(19). 
# ** Error (suppressible): testbench.sv(27): (vopt-12003) Variable 'ar[1].subar[1]' written by continuous and procedural assignments. See testbench.sv(19). 
# ** Error (suppressible): testbench.sv(27): (vopt-12003) Variable 'ar[1].subar[2]' written by continuous and procedural assignments. See testbench.sv(19). 
# ** Error (suppressible): testbench.sv(27): (vopt-12003) Variable 'ar[1].subar[3]' written by continuous and procedural assignments. See testbench.sv(19).
```

for this code:

```
module tb;

logic clk;

struct {
  struct {
    logic seq;
    logic assig;
    logic seq2;
  } subar [4];
} ar [2];


always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
  for (int i=0; i<2; i++) begin
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++) begin
      ar[i].subar[j].seq <= '1;
    end
  end
end

generate
  for (genvar i=0; i<2; i++) begin
    for (genvar j=0; j<4; j++) begin
      assign ar[i].subar[j].assig = '1;
    end
  end
endgenerate

always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
  for (int i=0; i<2; i++) begin
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++) begin
      ar[i].subar[j].seq2 <= '1;
    end
  end
end

endmodule
```

All the three logics are independent inside the structure and they aren't assigned in two different blocs.

EDA Playground: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/qYZ9

### Replacing the generate/assign with always_comb

```
always_comb begin
  for (int i=0; i<2; i++) begin
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++) begin
      ar[i].subar[j].assig = ar[i].subar[j].seq;
    end
  end
end
```

Replacing the generate with `assign` with an `always_comb` bloc gives a different result because all the `*.seq` signals are `X`.

Each `assig = seq` are all independent between each `i` and `j` iteration.

Why is this invalid?

Not being able to use a structure to group signals is excessively annoying...

Comment: This is a 'mentor' issue. Other compilers are ok. Report to mentor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is because of the rather pessimistic definition of *Longest static prefix* in section 11.5.3 of the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595). Basically, since `i` is a variable index, the long static prefix of `ar[i]` is `ar` and any array or struct selects succeeding that are irrelevant. Tools have been treating this more optimistically, but that has been a gradual process.

You can either suppress the error globally, or rewrite the code moving the `for` loop out of the block into a generate-`for` loop.

```
module tb;

logic clk;

struct {
  struct {
    logic seq;
    logic assig;
    logic seq2;
  } subar [4];
} ar [2];

for (genvar  i=0; i<2; i++) begin
  for (genvar  j=0; j<4; j++) begin
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
      ar[i].subar[j].seq <= '1;
    end
  end
end

  for (genvar i=0; i<2; i++) begin
    for (genvar j=0; j<4; j++) begin
      assign ar[i].subar[j].assig = '1;
    end
  end

for (genvar  i=0; i<2; i++) begin
  for (genvar  j=0; j<4; j++) begin
    always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
      ar[i].subar[j].seq2 <= '1;
    end
  end
end

endmodule
```

Comment: I can't move the loop outside, this was just a reproducible example. Is it guaranteed to work if I suppress the error? Otherwise I have to spend hours to change my code to support crap simulator behavior in 2022...

Comment: I suggest you downgrade the error to a warning and review any other warnings that might get produced.

Comment: This isn't crap simulator behavior though right, this is the behavior mandated by the LRM? Some simulators let you get away with the invalid behavior.

Comment: I quoted the LRM section that mandates it. Some simulators let you get away with crappy code too.